# iOS Vpn Connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, vpn, nevpnmanager

```
NEVPNProtocolIKEv2 *sec = [[NEVPNProtocolIKEv2 alloc] init];

sec.serverAddress = @"domain.com";
sec.remoteIdentifier = @"domain.com";
sec.username = @"username";
sec.localIdentifier = @"username";
sec.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethodSharedSecret;
```

How do I specify the user's password?

Server Password Type: EAP